# Apache HTTP SERVER has stopped working while using soap client in

Tags: php, apache, soap, xampp

Getting 
Apache HTTP SERVER has stopped working while using soap client in.
if SOAP API url not exist getting attached screen shot error again 
[Getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwaJ3.png)

I am using xampp v3.2.2 with php7.

Code which I am using

```
 try
    {
        $vies = new SoapClient('http://www.webservicex.com/spc/globalweather.asmx?wsdl', array('exceptions'=>true));
        var_dump($vies);
    }
    catch(SoapFault $e){
        $return_value = 'VAT check service is not available.';
        return $return_value;
    }
```

Note:- same code working fine with 5.6.

Thanks in advance